# Even if source and load impedances are matched, and current is flowing, wouldn't power be dissipated at the source equal to the load?

Tags: power, current, rf, transmission-line, reflection

Like for example a transmitter with 50 ohm impedance, I'm assuming this is real resistance, why would power not be dissipated also? Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Yes, power is dissipated as Justme & Andy aka said in their answers.  But, this is the condition under which the maximum amount of power is transferred to the load.

Comment: @SteveSh Only if you assume the sender impedance as given.  _Then_ the receiver power is maximised by matching the impedance.

Comment: Well, that assumption was stated in the question - that source & load impedances are matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example transmitter scenario where the "source" is a very fast switch. The switch can be replaced by a transistor or MOS device that operates similarly (**short** versus **open**):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8mCa4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Power flows from **BAT1**, through L1. Part of the time, **SW1** connects L1 to GND, which builds energy in **L1**. It also shorts C1 to GND, which *can* cause power to flow from output back to input if the timing is wrong. But if the timing is right, when SW1 shorts to GND, C1 is close to 0V, and remains at 0V while SW1 is shorted.

When **SW1** opens, stored energy in L1 is available to flow into the filter components C1, L2, C2, L3, C3, and load resistor R1. Note that **SW1** dissipates no power (assuming its shorted condition is indeed zero ohms, and switching time is very fast).
So this source signal dissipates no power, but does deliver power to R1. If timing is right, it describes a CLASS-E power amplifier having very high efficiency, where nearly 100% of power pulled from **BAT1** ends up delivered to R1.
It is a very non-linear signal source, so the linear concept of *source impedance* must be applied with care. This signal source has no dissipative components, yet on average, a DC current flows from **BAT1**. Would you call \$V_{BAT1}\over I_{BAT1}\$ a source impedance?

This same argument might be applied to a switching power supply. Power flows from input source to load through reactive components (and switches) with high efficiency, perhaps 90%: much better than the best linear model of 50% dissipated in source, 50% dissipated in load.

Comment: Hi thankyou so much for the response here, so in essense here, the impedance at the load (the v/i sense) is only from imaginary components? If thats the case then i guess that means no real power is used on the source side? Thanks

Comment: That load resistor R1 can only dissipate power, and store none. All the L's and C's can store power, and can dissipate none. Andy's transmission line scenario is similar to L's and C's. Looking into the source end of a transmission line (or LC network), real power is only **accepted** if a dissipative load R exists at the load end. I'm considering L, C, X-line as ideal, lossless. If the load end is open, no real power flows from the source. it might look inductive, capacitive, a short-circuit, or an open-circuit depending on frequency.

Answer (score 2):

But power is dissipated.

When you have e.g. signal generator with 50 ohm source impedance and e.g. oscilloscope with 50 ohm termination impedance, half of the power is lost in the source impedance and the other half in the termination impedance.

Comment: does this mean the source impedance is real?

Answer (score 1):

> Like for example a transmitter with 50 ohm impedance, I'm assuming this is real resistance, why would power not be dissipated also? Hope my question makes sense.

There is no necessity for "real resistance".  The point is to establish a relation between voltage and current in order to minimize reflections.  Of course this is easy to do with a resistor, but if energy efficiency is of utmost importance, one can just use a shunt resistor and amplify its voltage falloff to let the final amplifier stage exhibit a *virtual* output impedance of 50 ohms.

That may make some sense if you work from a fixed power rail limiting the output voltage and with a half-duplex or unidirectional connection where you don't need to accommodate superimposed incoming signals with a commensurate signal strength.

But for many applications, a resistor will be the easiest way to provide a resistance to the line, and having part of the voltage drop consumed by an external resistor may better dissipate heat.

Comment: Hi, thanks in fact that leads to another question on what exactly is the "source impedance",  like on a radio. when nothing is connected to the antenna, is the total impedance basically infinity, is the 50ohm standard due to some components in parallel to the signal and ground? Thanks

Comment: @Georgekirby The source impedance describes the relation between voltage changes and current changes on the source.  An output impedance of 50 Ohm means that an externally applied current of 1mA will cause the voltage to shift by 50mV.  Waves through the transmission line arrive with a relation between voltage and current: if the voltage is allowed to go up in proper relation to the current, waves will get completely absorbed, meaning that what gets sent out remains unchanged.  Otherwise the outgoing signal gets superimposed with a reflection of the incoming.

Answer (score 0):

> *Even if source and load impedances are matched, and current is
> flowing, wouldn't power be dissipated at the source equal to the load?*

Yes it would.

However, noting the these tags: -

[image]

We don't have to use a source impedance. Providing that the load matches the transmission line's characteristic impedance then, we won't get reflections and, all the source power is delivered to the load.

Comment: Hi im a bit confused by this, i know there is content online showing why theres no reflections ect, but interms of the foward current, surley the the source side of thhe whole thing then disapates power. Secondly why is it there isnt a "source impedance"? Thanks

Comment: The source supplies power but, theoretically it doesn't dissipate any locally. You don't need a source impedance to drive a transmission line @Georgekirby <-- no harm or reflections will occur when the source impedance is zero ohm.

Comment: Thanks, so why wouldn't there be any reflections if the source is zero

Comment: Reflections only happen when a signal (that has travelled down a cable) hits an impedance that doesn't match the characteristic impedance of the cable. The source has zero electrical length and, can drive the cable without creating a reflection; the source sees the cable as 50 ohm and 20 mA per volt pass into the cable. Not so at the far end of the cable @Georgekirby

Comment: @Georgekirby please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Hi so you could connect a 75 ohm coax to the back of a radio transmitter? Providing the antenna was 75ohm

Comment: Try reading the link again.